# Are module categories over a semisimple category semisimple?

Tags: category-theory, modules

Let $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes, \oplus, I, a, r, l)$ be an abelian semisimple monoidal category, then is it necessary that all module categories over $\mathcal{C}$ be semisimple?

I can convince myself that they need to be additive and have indecomposable objects, but I cannot see semisimplicity.

Thanks

Comment: I don't really work with module categories over monoidal categories, but shouldn't you have some 'finite-dimensionality' condition on your module category for something like this to hold? Also, you do assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is semisimple right? (it's written in the title but not in the body of your post).

Comment: I edited my question, thank. 
Finite dimensionality for hom-set you mean?

Comment: Can you give me a reference where you studied these things? I'm not familiar enough with these concepts to answer straightaway. If no-one else answers, I might think about it.

Comment: Well, taking $\mathcal C:=\mathbf{finVect}_k$, wouldn't that mean that every (finitely generated, associative, unital) algebra over $k$ is semisimple?

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thanks! Basically this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139v1

Comment: @Berci: Sorry I did not get your point. You mean having semisimple algebras in $\mathcal{C}$ means we have semisimple module categories?

Comment: Yes, a ring is semisimple iff all its modules are semisimple. I guess the same holds for $k$-algebras.

Comment: @Berci Okay. But I cannot get its connection with modules over a semisimple category.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they usually are not.  To elaborate on Berci's comment, if $k$ is a field and $\mathcal{C}$ is the usual monoidal category of (finite-dimensional) vector spaces over $k$, then for any $k$-algebra $A$, the category of (finitely generated) right $A$-modules is a module category over $\mathcal{C}$ (by just using the usual tensor product over $k$: if $V$ is a vector space and $M$ is an $A$-module, then $V\otimes_k M$ is again an $A$-module).  This category is semisimple iff $A$ is a semisimple ring, so any non-semisimple $k$-algebra gives a counterexample (e.g., $A=k[x]$, or $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ if you want some stronger finiteness conditions).

(It's not clear to me what kind of finiteness assumptions you want to be making here.  If your definition of "semisimple" requires every object to be a finite coproduct of simple objects, for instance, then you can get an even easier example by just taking the category of all vector spaces as a module category over the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces.  In that case, it's completely unreasonable to hope for a module category to be semisimple unless you also impose some finiteness assumptions on it.)